# Visual Studio 2013 error while trying to run

Tags: visual-studio-2013

[image: Error while trying to run project: Invalid pointer]

While I try to run it keep on alerting me "Error while trying to run project: Invalid pointer", please help

Comment: Try updating your Visual Studio.  See answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27915050/2434565)

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem is caused by importing VS2010 settings. Anyway, this solved the problem for me:

1. Go to `\Users\<Username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0`
2. Rename the folder to '_12.0'
3. Repeat for `\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0`
4. Open Registry Editor
5. Go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0`
6. Rename the key to `_12.0`