# Invalid pointer in Visual Studio 2015 when I run the project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-1.0

I have updated Visual Studio 2015 with Update 3 because I want to add asp.net core. After I updated Visual Studio, this error starts to occur:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VS2015 Error while trying to run application: Invalid Pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32270428/vs2015-error-while-trying-to-run-application-invalid-pointer)

Comment: I have try to fixed like this  link but not working..I had updated visual studio 2015 update 3 then this error has been occurred..

Comment: See similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26072858/how-do-you-solve-the-invalid-pointer-issue-in-visual-studio-2013